# Perl regex expand variable and die if file does not exist

Tags: regex, perl

i Found this line:

```
perl -p -i -e 'BEGIN{ -f $ARGV[0] or die"no file" } s/foo/bar/'
non-existent-file.txt
```

And i would like to make it work for my case. Expand variables inside the substitution but im not familiar with Perl syntax at all :)

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 'BEGIN{ -f $ARGV[0] or die".HEAD file is missing" }'
"s|^\\Q${repo}:\\E.+$|${newrepo}|gm" .HEAD;
```

.HEAD file is missing at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.

Comment: Your quote at the end of first line should be after the second double quote of line 2 (just before `.HEAD`). Furthermore, is there a file named `.HEAD` in your current directory?

Comment: Yes .HEAD exist if i put single-quote after the double-quote then my variables does not expand.

Comment: Shell variables aren't Perl variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't (try to) generate Perl code in a shell script!!!

```
perl -i -pe'
   BEGIN {
      $repo    = shift(@ARGV);
      $newrepo = shift(@ARGV);

      open(my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0])
         or die("Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!\n");
   }
   s|^\Q$repo:\E.+$|$newrepo|g;
' "$repo" "$newrepo" .HEAD
```

or

```
export repo
export newrepo
perl -i -pe'
   BEGIN {
      open(my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0])
         or die("Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!\n");
   }
   s|^\Q$ENV{repo}:\E.+$|$ENV{newrepo}|g;
' .HEAD
```

or

```
repo="$repo" newrepo="$newrepo" perl -i -pe'
   BEGIN {
      open(my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0])
         or die("Can't open $ARGV[0]: $!\n");
   }
   s|^\Q$ENV{repo}:\E.+$|$ENV{newrepo}|g;
' .HEAD
```

Notes:

- The file can exist even if `-f` returns false. The actual error is in `$!`. Using `open` is even more accurate at checking if the file can be opened than `-f`.
- I added line breaks added for readability. Remove them if you want, but there's no need to do so.
- I removed the useless `-0777`, and the `/m` that became useless as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Perl variables aren't the same as shell variables. To pass values to the script, you can use paramteres, but then you need to stop processing the input on the first [eof](http://p3rl.org/eof), otherwise Perl would treat the parameters as filenames, too:

```
perl -i -0777 -ne 'BEGIN { ($file, $repo, $new) = @ARGV;
                           die "$file missing\n" unless -f $file;
                   }
                   s/^\Q$repo:\E.+$/$new/gm;
                   print;
                   last if eof;
                  ' -- .HEAD "$repo" "$newrepo"
```

Or, open the file yourself:

```
if perl -0777 -e '($file, $repo, $new) = @ARGV;
                  open $FH, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";
                  while (<$FH>) {
                      s/^\Q$repo:\E.+$/$new/gm;
                      print;
                  }' -- .HEAD "$repo" "$newrepo" > newfile
then
   mv newfile .HEAD
fi
```

Comment: Explanation of differences between the two: Because the second snippet doesn't use `ARGV`, `-i` would have no effect, so you need to handle the "in-place" aspect yourself. On the plus side, this means you can avoid clobbering `.HEAD` if an error occurs.